# Pyautogui saving image permission denied

Tags: python

```
>>> pyautogui.screenshot()  
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1920x1080 at 0x486FAF0>
```

This works but when I try to save it to a png file... I get this

> > > pyautogui.screenshot('test12.png')
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >               pyautogui.screenshot('test12.png')
> > >             File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze__init__.py", line 288, in                _screenshot_win32
> > >               im.save(imageFilename)
> > >             File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1687, in save
> > >               fp = builtins.open(fp, "wb")
> > >           PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test12.png'

Any help on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are running the code from a directory you don't have write permissions, you would need to give yourself write permissions or save the the file where you do have write permissions passing the path.